# Windows 2008 member server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I know what a DC server is, but I dont understand the concept of a member server. It is a server without AD and roles right? So why create an "empty" server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sergey stated, a member server is any server joined to the domain that isn't a DC. Examples of member servers include: email servers, file servers, print servers, DHCP servers, DNS servers, web servers, CRM, ERP, database, yada-yada-yada, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 3):

Member server - it's any server not operating as domain controller. It can "carry" any other role/service, or work as workstation.